# How Can Wind Chimes Be Mounted On The Second Story?

Tags: siding, vinyl-siding

I have some Japanese cast iron chimes (Small, they fit in the palm of your hand and are about 0.5kg)
[image: Japanese Chime]

Can these be mounted against the vinyl siding outside my room on the second story of my house?

How would I do this? (I've done roofing work before, so I know all the usual safety warnings about ladders, heights, etc)

Answer (score 3):

1. Open window of your room.
2. Remove screen.
3. Lean out (carefully) and screw eyebolt to bottom of window frame.  Something like [this](https://www.e-rigging.com/3-4-x-3-1-8-Zinc-Plated-Screw-Eye?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI_p7xudab4QIVUr7ACh1lXAFhEAQYAiABEgJNjvD_BwE).

[image: eye screw]

Bottom of window frame because A: easier and B: chime will not hit window in strong wind.

4. Attach chime to eyebolt with carabiner, or chain, or something else appropriate for a site exposed to weather.

If the chime annoys you or your new roommate or you want to swap it out for better chime, or you need to clean it out, it will be easy to get to without ladder or going on roof.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use a plant hanger

[image: plant hanger]

Fasten it to the side frame of your window.  This puts the chime far enough from the wall it doesn't hit the house, but is close enough to the window to be very hearable.

In passing:  Chime sounds vary hugely on placement.  We have a large stainless steel one that was on the patio.  It took a fairly strong wind for it to sound.  I moved it about 5 feet horizontally and 4 feet up, using a higher tree branch.  It sounds about 3 times as much now.

You can adjust to some extend by changing the length of the string, and by adding area to the the wind catcher to make it sound more, adding mass to make it sound less.  You can also adjust the tone by your choice of striker.  A metal striker induces more high frequency sounds.  Wooden or hard rubber strikers tend to induce the lower primary tone, with fewer harmonics.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with some **[Window Suction Cup Hangers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GLC11LN)**. You could install these from inside the home if your windows tilt (like most do) for cleaning. Your wind chimes are small and would hang easily on these and they would not hit the glass pane if the wind was blowing harder than usual. No need for climbing or marring up your vinyl siding with this option.

[image]

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but I'm getting bad flashbacks of a soap container mounted in a similar fashion that kept falling in the bathtub.

Comment: So 0.5kg falling 2 storeys onto a someone below - brilliant...

Comment: This is not the "wet it with your tongue and slap it on the window" suction cup. If you look a little closer you will see a small mechanism. When you press this against the glass it seals the suction cup perfectly, creating an air-tight vacuum which significantly increases the suction cup strength, providing maximum hold and stability.